# SQL Database Keeps Crashing

Tags: mysql

MySQL Database keeps crashing. This is crashing 5 times a day on the table: ec_options i.e wp_options

I don't know how to format on here the error output from cat /var/lib/mysql/HOSTNAME.com.err and put it on pastie.

http://pastie.org/pastes/9954066/text?key=km6dchv1ve4rviplodr3nw

I wanted to show whats in the mysql configuration here:

```
root@server1 [~]# cat /var/lib/mysql/my.cnf 
[mysqld]
innodb_use_native_aio = 0
default_storage_engine = "MyISAM"
```

Comment: mysqld_safe mysqld restarted, so find the error log (you can find it in my.cnf  under log-error=). Something there should be stating why it is restarting your MySQL db.

Comment: Please describe your hardware configuration. Please know that an AWS micro VM doesn't have enough RAM for a MySQL server and a web server with a WordPress instance, unless you're a tuning wizard.